# midiOutShortMsg and midiOutSetVolume with output in stereo

Tags: c++, winapi, midi

I'm writing C++ code to output midi messages. I need this to work in stereo, so that some notes are played through the left channel/speaker, others through the right. If I call midiOutSetVolume(midiOutHandle, 0xFFFF) followed by several calls to midiOutShortMsg, with each call separated by a few hundred milliseconds, the notes come through the left speaker. Likewise if I first call midiOutSetVolume(midiOutHandle, 0xFFFF0000) before the calls to midiOutShortMsg everything comes out the right speaker. However if I attempt to simultaneously output one note through the left speaker and one through the right by doing the following:

```
midiOutSetVolume(midiOutHandle, 0xFFFF);
midiOutShortMsg(...);
midiOutSetVolume(midiOutHandle, 0xFFFF0000);
midiOutShortMsg(...);
```

Both notes simply come out the right speaker. I thought if I perhaps had 2 separate handles to the device I could set one to play the left channel notes, the other the right. However if I try and open 2 handles to the same device via 2 calls to midiOutOpen I get an MMSYSERR_ALLOCATED error on the second call.

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use **two channels** and set the **pan** on each channel. Then play your notes for the left speaker on channel 0, and your notes for the right speaker on channel 1.

To set the channel of a note, your *Note On* event has 4 bits for the channel:

```
1001nnnn (Note On)
nnnn = channel number (0..15)
```

So use channel **0** for your left speaker and channel **1** for your right speaker.

To set the pan of a channel, output a *Control Change* message to that channel:

```
Status byte: 1011nnnn (Control Change)
nnnn = channel number (0..15)

First data byte - Controller number: 0ccccccc
Second data byte - Controller value: 0vvvvvvv
ccccccc = 10 (0x0A) for Pan
vvvvvvv = 0..127 (left = 0, right = 127)
```

Set the pan of channel 0 to 0, and the pan of channel 1 to 127.

See the [MIDI messages reference](http://www.midi.org/techspecs/midimessages.php#3) for more detail. Also, here is a [short list](http://www.indiana.edu/~emusic/cntrlnumb.html) of Control Change numbers.

---

**UPDATE:** Using *simultaneous percussion kits* requires MIDI standard XG or GM Level 2. Read about them [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_MIDI_standards). Which method you use depends on your device's MIDI standard:

- XG: Send a **Bank Select** Control Change message (controller number **0**) with value **127** (0x7F).
- GM Level 2: Use channels **10** and **11** for your two kits (ie. 9 and 10 when you send Note On).

Comment: Thanks hugely for the reply. I'm actually using percussion instruments, which are set to channel 10, hence can't use multiple channels. I tried setting the pan rather than setting the volume but the result was the same, everything ended up coming out the one speaker.

Comment: Is it possible to set another channel to play percussion? Your method works perfectly using standard GM instruments. If I can get 2 channels playing percussion I am there.

Comment: @AndrewKlinkhamer: Yes, it is possible, depending on your MIDI device. Answer updated.